# how do you customize url?

Tags: file, url, location, customization

www.example.ca/article/563/

I see the above link in a dynamic site. I am working on the site, and there is no folder called 'article' and obviously '563' is dynamically generated as well. I found out I had to edit the article.php page which is located in the root folder to make the changes I wanted, but my question is, how do I make urls appear different from what the actual file location is on the server.

Comment: Rewrite rules will do it, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is commonly called "[URL Rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine)". It can be done with appropriate configuration of your webserver, for example Apache's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/) provides a way to modify incoming URL requests, dynamically, based on regular expression rules.